PSO in TSP or VRP
I am seeking some guidance regarding the implementation of velocity update in a Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) approach for route planning. I am currently working on developing a system that optimizes delivery routes for customer bookings. In this context, each particle in the PSO represents a complete route configuration. For instance, with 5 customers and 3 vehicles, a valid particle position might be [[1], [4, 2], [3, 5]], indicating:

Vehicle 1 serves customer
Vehicle 2 serves customers 4 and 2.
Vehicle 3 serves customers 3 and 5.

However, I am struggling to understand how to effectively calculate the velocity and utilize it to update the routes (particle positions) during the PSO iterations.
Specifically, I have questions about:

pbest - current_position: How is this difference calculated for each
customer assignment, and how does the c1*r1 weight influence it?
Velocity Interpretation: What does the resulting velocity vector
represent in the context of route planning?
Position Update: How        does the velocity guide the update of the particle's position (route
configuration)?

For reference, the general velocity update formula in PSO is:
v(t) = (inertia * previous_velocity) + (c1r1 * (pbest - current_position)) + (c2r2 * (gbest - current_position))
I would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations on how to adapt the velocity update for route planning in PSO, particularly addressing the points mentioned above.
